# How to change fontsize of syncfusion treenavigator items UWP?

Tags: windows, uwp, syncfusion, uwp-xaml

I'm new to windows phone dev. My team used syncfusion for the dropdown treenavigator. I've tried tweaking the colors, margins and padding but wasn't able to change the FontSize. Any tips?

```
<sfnavigation: sfTreeNavigator>
    <sfnavigation:sfTreeNavigatorItem FontSize="5"/>
</sfnavigation:sfTreeNavigator>
```

Sorry, my laptop crashed and I couldn't remember the setter syntax but yeah tried in that too. It won't update.

Comment: Please provide some sample code so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: This is a paid third party tool, please ask the syncfusion team for supporting.

Comment: @Sunteen I tried but no support is answering me yet. It's kinda urgent so I was wondering if people could answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the sample which i have attached? I'm able to change the FontSize for SfTreeNavigatorItem.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfTreeNavigatorUWPSample-85286901)

Code which i have used are

```
<Style  TargetType="navigation:SfTreeNavigatorItem">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

Regards,

Jegan Raj M